# Sybase is loading incorrect numeric data sent by Spring batch - Jdbc Template

Tags: spring-batch, sybase, jdbctemplate

I have a ETL job built using spring batch and DAO layer uses Spring's jdbc template.The issue is with loading of numeric datatype. When the batch is running for large number of records, good amount of numeric values(not all) will be loaded incorrectly(pattern is that value will be multiplied by 10^scale).

I am using batchUpdate method and preparedStatement. The driver used is jconn4.jar from sybase version 7.0.7.

I am getting the values printed while setting the ps, and do not see the values being manipulated at java side.

Could someone please advice on what could be causing this.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Further info Sybase version 15.7, Spring core and jdbc version 4.2.6, Spring batch version 3.0.4, java version 8

Also has someone used sybPreparedStatement from jConnect library? I found a sybase infocenter link where they recommend using it perticularly when using numeric data types but I do find the documentation around how to use this ps insignificant. Could you pl share if you have tried using SybPS and what were the challenges, and if you could successfully use that.

Comment: Which version of database are you using? Which version of Spring? Which version of Java?